# How to minimize screen flickering when carrying out multiple graphic changes in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am implementing fullscreen function (and restore) in my application, which will hide toolbars, few other qt widgets to show a single window in fullscreen. For the same I pass individual high level commands to hide/show each item. But as qt processes each I see multiple intermediate screens. I am looking out for command to make the process smooth and avoid seeing intermediate visuals. Currently I am hiding the main window completely and display it back after all modifications are complete but not satisfied as the application disappears for 2-3 seconds.

I am looking for some solution to avoid display of multiple intermediate screens making transition more smooth.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able achieve this using [`updatesEnabled` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop) of `QWidget`.

Disable updates for the widget which contains all the child widgets and layouts you want updated (it might be your top level window, or perhaps QMainWindow central widget, or whatever), do the changes, then re-enable updates.